# Displays horizontal and vertical images using the CSS

Tags: css

I have a fixed-width tape images. Horizontal well displayed (the width of the tape), but the vertical do not fit on the entire screen.

Look at here http://didi.url.ph/design (click first block with cat) :)

Now I have:

```
    #ajaxcontent .field-item img { 
        height: auto;
        width: 100%; 
    }
```

How to make:
the maximum width of the image - the width of the tape,
the maximum height - the height of the screen.

[so should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZTTh.png)

It does not work:

```
    #ajaxcontent .field-item img {
         max-width: 100%;
         max-height: 80vh;
    }
```

Because the image is stretched disproportionately.

Are there any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

**CSS**

```
#ajaxcontent {
    background: #ffffff none repeat scroll 0 0;
    height: 90vh;
    margin: 40px auto;
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: The tape (#ajaxcontent) is not necessary to change. 

I want that vertical image has view as {height: 80vh; width: auto;}

Comment: @Kate You cannot set the same height to all images and expect they have the same aspect ratio, because they are different (portrait/landscape)